# Can we just set it?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dirac-delta, weak-derivatives

Suppose that we have $G(\overline{x},\overline{y})=-\frac{1}{4 \pi} \frac{1}{||\overline{x}-\overline{y}||}$ for $\overline{x}, \overline{y} \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

I want to calculate $\Delta{G(\overline{x}, \overline{y})}$.

I have found that $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{x_1^2}} \left( -\frac{1}{4 \pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2+(x_3-y_3)^2}}\right)=\frac{1}{4 \pi} \frac{(x_2-y_2)^2+(x_3-y_3)^2-2(x_1-y_1)^2}{((x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2+(x_3-y_3)^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$

Making the corresponding for $x_2$ and $x_3$ we get that $\Delta{G(\overline{x}, \overline{y})}=0$ for $\overline{x} \neq \overline{y}$.

Can we just say that $\Delta{G(\overline{x}, \overline{y})}=\delta(\overline{x}-\overline{y})$ if $\overline{x}=\overline{y}$ or do we have to show something in order to set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have shown above, we know that $\Delta G$ is a distribution supported at the origin. To show that $\Delta G(x,y)=\delta(x-y)$, we can use its homogeneity of $-3$, $\frac1{\|x\|}$ has homogeneity $-1$ and $\Delta$ reduces homogeneity by $2$, and the [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem):
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{B(0,r)}\Delta G(x,0)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}n\cdot\nabla G(x,0)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac x{\|x\|}\cdot\frac x{4\pi\|x\|^3}\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac1{4\pi\|x\|^2}\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Could you explain it further to me why we have to show that $$\int_{B(0,r)}\Delta G(x,0)\,\mathrm{d}x=1$$ ?

Comment: Do we use the fact that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \delta(x-y) dy=1$ ?

Comment: Since $\Delta G(x,0)$ is supported at the origin, it is a sum of the delta function and its derivatives. Looking at the homogeneity, we can tell it is $c\delta(x)$, but we don't know what $c$ is. The computation above shows that $c=1$.

Comment: Why do we pick the set $B(0,r)$ ? Also, I haven't really understood it. Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: Since $\Delta G(x,0)=0$ away from the origin, we can integrate over any region containing the origin and get the same answer. The ball of radius $r$ and its boundary are very simple regions over which to integrate.

Comment: So no matter which set we would pick , would we get the same result? Why does $\int_{B(0,r)} \Delta G(x,0) dx=1$ imply that $\Delta G(x,y)=\delta(x-y)$ ?

Comment: $\Delta G(x,0)$ has homogeneity $-3$ and is supported at the origin. This means it must be a constant multiple of $\delta(x)$. The integral tells us the constant is $1$.

Comment: How do we check the homogeneity of $\Delta G(x,0)$ ?

Comment: As I mention in my answer, "$\frac1{\|x\|}$ has homogeneity $-1$ and $\Delta$ reduces homogeneity by $2$".

Comment: How do we apply the divergence theorem? How do we compute $n$ ?

Comment: MlI applied the Divergence Theorem above. Since we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $n=3$.

Comment: Don't we have at the boundary that $||x||=r$ ? How do we deduce that $$\int_{\partial{B(0,r)}} \frac{1}{4 \pi ||x||^2} d \sigma=1$$?

Comment: Yes. The area of the sphere is $4\pi r^2$ and $\frac1{4\pi\|x\|^2}=\frac1{4\pi r^2}$. Therefore, the integral is $1$.

Comment: Nice... Could you maybe explain to me why $\Delta G$ is not a function?

Comment: Because it is not defined for x=y?

Comment: If $\Delta G(x,0)$ were a function, then since it is $0$ everywhere but the origin, its integral would be $0$. However, above, we've shown that its integral over any region containing the origin is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

First fix $y=0$.  We can recover the general case by setting $x=\bar{x}-\bar{y}$.  Now $\Delta G(x,0) = \delta(x)$ by definition means that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}G(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx = \phi(0)$ for any smooth compactly supported function $\phi$.  This is by the definition of the distribution derivative (weak derivative).

We know $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}G(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx =\int_{B_R(0)}G(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx +\int_{B_R(0)^C}G(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx =\int_{B_R(0)}G(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx.$  This is because $\int_{B_R(0)^C}G(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx=\int_{B_R(0)^C}\Delta G(x)\phi(x)dx=0$, using integration by parts (which we can do because $G$ is differentiable away from the origin).

At this point you can evaluate $\int_{B_R(0)}G(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx$ by using some form of the divergence theorem as robjohn shows.

Comment: We could also show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \Delta G(x,0) dx=\int_{B(0,r)} \Delta G(x,0) dx=1$, right? But I haven't understood how we apply the divergence theorem. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Especially, how do we compute $n$ ?

Comment: I want to be clear that $\Delta G$ is not a function and it can't be integrated.  My answer goes into the details of what is meant by $\int \Delta G(x,0) dx$.  This is special notation in the same way that you might say that $\int \delta(x) dx =1 $.  In the divergence theorem $n$ is the unit normal vector at $x\in\partial B_R(0)$.  Since we are working with a sphere this vector is $x/||x||$.

Comment: Why isn't $\Delta G$  a function?

Comment: It isn't twice differentiable at the origin.  You must use the notion of distributions to make sense of $\Delta G$.